# Gradle - Create A Tar Of All Subprojects

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build that builds a war file in each of the sub-projects when I run "gradle war".

I now want to create a dist or a tar task in the root project that adds all the war files into a tar.

How do I run a task that depends on specific tasks of sub-projects?

I tried this but the war tasks don't get run.

```
task explodedDist() {
    dependsOn tasks.withType(War)
    println "Finish"
}
```

This runs, however, I would rather not have to explicitly list the names of all the sub-projects in the root task.

```
task explodedDist()  {
    dependsOn ':first:war'
    dependsOn ':second:war'

    println "Finish"
}
```

Is there a better way using "subprojects" or the like?

I am essentially building all sub-projects then taring them up as a dist. This seems like it should be fairly common. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: It's important to understand that these `println`s happen when the script gets evaluated (configuration phase), not when the task runs (execution phase). To achieve the latter, the `println`s would have to be wrapped with `doLast { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task dist(type: Tar) {
    from { subprojects.war }
}
```